# Xamarin.Android Java Exit Code 1 when build with Android version 31

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin Android project and set the "Compile using Android version. (Target Framework) at Android 12.

[image]

I am able to build successfully the project on version 30 (Android 11) and below.
[image]

However whenever I change the Target Android version to version 31 (Android 12 and above, it build fails with below error
[image]
[image]

> "java.exe" exited with code 1.

What's the code changes needed when we go to Version 31?

Comment: You can try to delete the obj/ bin folders, then restart VS, and rebuild it.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: 9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1489,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.

Comment: @OLIVER Check my answer to see if you can solve it this way too.

Comment: I also have this problem, and it is the upgrade to API 31 that is definitely the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to compile the project without any issue by using the settings as below at "Properties > Android Option".

[image]
[image]

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me. So we have to choose: be able to build, or be able to deploy, but not both!

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue when using widgets. Builds just fine in API 30, but as soon as I go over 30 it fails with:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       "java.exe" exited with code 1.  widgetSample.Android

I tried the settings above, no change.

Anyone know what I need to change to make  this work with widgets? Here is the sample/program for anyone interested to have a look: https://github.com/salvesen/widgetSample

To be able to release new apps to play store it needs to be API 31 and above and I cant seem to get any widget apps to work on API 31 or above, so I cant release :/

Comment: You are correct. 6 months later this is still a problem

Answer (score 0):

After much pain, I updated Visual Studio 2022 to the latest updates, when that was done VS asked me to update various Android tools. Then I noticed SDK 33 was available so I selected that, went though the usual prompts, reboots, accepting of installing this and that, etc., hard-cleans, etc., also Xamarin Forms upgrade with nuget, oh and updated my AndroidManifest because things had changed and I needed something called android:export=true or something in a few places. Changed Archive to be a bundle from whatever it was before. So many hours later, my app can now be uploaded to the app store. Yay.

Comment: Try to [edit] this according to [answer], because it currently gives more of an impression of being a log of your suffering than being a helpful and clear answer.